# Is it possible to convert a MVC C# List<int> to an javascript array?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to convert a MVC C# List to an javascript array?

```
var jsArray = @Model.IntList;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keywords: *c#  json serializers*.

Comment: Related: [How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470702/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-liststring-to-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 8):

You can do

```
<script type="text/jscript">
  var jsonVariable = @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.IntList)));//using Newtonsoft
//or you can use below
//var jsonVariable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IntList))
</script>
```

Comment: For future, if you need some json data, take a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use below approach for convert @Model.IntList to javascript array

```
<script type="text/jscript">
  var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IntList))
</script>
```

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493291/11011693