# How to pass an array as a URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I would like to pass an array and added to a link on my page as a URL parameter, because later on the server side I need the values from the array. How should I do that?

```
myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];

$('#myLink').attr({"href" : '/myLink?array=' + myArray});
```

I am not sure if that is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: *"How should I do that?"* That really depends on what server side language you are using and how it expects the data to be formatted. E.g. does the server expect JSON? Or a parameter per value? A comma separated list of values? Something else?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can try `$.param({ array: myArray }, true);`

Comment: The answer is you can't, not with Javascript. All solutions you end up would not be actually something you would pass. What you can do is pass an array like parameter and throw back with you server side languague. Why you need to pass the entire array anyway?

Comment: @FelixKling I am using laravel on server side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417265/how-to-send-an-array-via-the-url-in-javascript-jquery Check the above link.

Answer (score 84):

You can serialize the JSON:

```
myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
var arrStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myArray));
$('#myLink').attr({ href: '/myLink?array=' + arrStr });
```

If your parsing (on the next page) is done via JavaScript too, you'll conversely use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). In PHP it would be [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: "encodeURIComponent"  is a standard js function?

Comment: @rezaakhlaghi: yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: In PHP I've used `urldecode()` as well to convert it all back. So it's `json_decode(urldecode($your_query_string))`

Answer (score 22):

try this

```
$('#myLink').attr({"href" : '/myLink?array=' + myArray.join(',')});
```

on server: capture and split data.

Answer (score 17):

It should not depend on the server side: By the URI standard specification, all parameters must have one name and should have one value. But there can be several parameters with the same name, which is the right way to serialize an array:

http://server/context?array=aaa&array=bbb&array=ccc&otherparameter=x

You could do it like this:

```
var s="";
for (var i=0;i< myArray.length;i++)
{
  s+="&myArray="+myArray[i];
}
var url="http://server/context?"+s;
```

Comment: this good but need to edit 
`s+="&myArray="+myArray[i];` 
to 
    `s+="&myArray[]="+myArray[i];`

Comment: @megyptm No, not at all. My approach will produce multiple values to parameter named "myArray". As you say, it would be to a parameter named "myArray[]".

Comment: Why not use `URLSearchParams`? with methods `.append` and `.toString`

Answer (score 15):

I'd go with this approach,

```
var myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', ];

var myArrayQry = myArray.map(function(el, idx) {
    return 'myArray[' + idx + ']=' + el;
}).join('&');

// myArray[0]=aaa&myArray[1]=bbb&myArray[2]=ccc
```

Then, I retrieve the URL query params as an array on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

How to pass an array of strings as URL parameters:

```js
const myLink = 'https:/example.com/api'
const myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
let apiUrl = `${myLink}/query?`;

myArray.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (i === 0) {
    apiUrl += `array=${x}`;
  } else {
    apiUrl += `&array=${x}`;
  }
});

console.log(apiUrl);
document.body.innerHTML = apiUrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```
var myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
var baseUrl = '/myLink';
var paramName = 'array=';

var arrayAsString = '?' + paramName + myArray.join('&' + paramName);
var urlWithParams = baseUrl + arrayAsString;

window.location.href = urlWithParams;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
myArrString = JSON.stringify(myArray.join("_"))

$('#myLink').attr({"href" : `/myLink?array=${myArrString}`});
```

And then when you need it later on you can parse it and then get back your array like so

```
JSON.parse(myArrString).split("_")
```

Answer (score 0):

One another way to do that is as the following

```
import Router from 'next/router'

Router.push({
  pathname: '/search',
  query: {searchTerm: searchRef.current ? searchRef.current["value"] : '', codeSets: JSON.stringify(selectedCodeSets)}
}, '/search');
```

selectedCodeSets in this example is an array from state data

```
const [selectedCodeSets, setSelectedCodeSets] = useState<any>(['1']);
```

We can parse that data in the directed page like below

```
import {withRouter} from 'next/router'

const DaComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
        let codeSets = JSON.parse(props.router.query.codeSets);
  }, [props.router]);
};

export default withRouter(DaComponent);
```