# How do I pass MVC model data to AngularJS controller scope

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

In my application I'm returning the view below which uses this TestViewModel.

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<string> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model AdminSite.Models.TestsViewModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Tests";
    }

    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    </hgroup>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Angular/Tests.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="testsTable">
            <div ng-controller="TableController">
                <table my-table options="options"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see I'm using AngularJS to create a DataTable, what I would like though is that instead of the table data "aaData" being hardcoded I want it to be from TestViewModel model.

```
var app = angular.module('testsTable', []);

app.directive('myTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var dataTable = element.dataTable(scope.options);
        },
        scope: {
            options: "="
        }
    };
});


app.controller('TableController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        aoColumns: [
            {
                "sTitle": "Col 1",
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Col 2"
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Col 3"
            }
        ],
        aoColumnDefs: [{
            "bSortable": true,
        }],
        bJQueryUI: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        aaData: [
            ["A", "B", "C"],
            ["A", "B", "C"],

        ]
    };
}]);
```

I think I may have to create another directive to bind the model e.g

```
<table my-table options="options" model-data="@Model.Tests"></table>
```

but I'm not really sure how Angular directives work exactly, how I would write said directive & how it binds it to the scope

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470702/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-liststring-to-a-javascript-array/18470931#18470931)

You could directly inject the values into JavaScript:

```
//View.cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrayOfArrays = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Addresses)');
</script>
```

See [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740.aspx)

Alternatively you can get the values via Ajax:

```
public ActionResult GetValues()
{
    // logic
    // Edit you don't need to serialize it just return the object

    return Json(new { Addresses: lAddressGeocodeModel });
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetValues")',
        success: function(result) {
            // do something with result
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

See [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: it's not the serialisation part I'm struggling with it moreso how I set the scope to use that serialised data.

what I want to achieve really is
    var arrayOfArrays = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Addresses)')

then

$scope.option.aaData = arrayOfArrays

Comment: You can create this scope variable inside your controller and then assign the value to it. I think you are using DataTables. If so, the table should get updated after you cahnge the array content. In your HTML just use {{myVariable=JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Addresses)');""}}

Comment: In your HTML just use `{{options.aaData=JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(@Model.Tests)');""}}` before the table tag. Let me know if it worked so I'll edit my answer.

Comment: still no luck, just in case the serialisation part isn't working ive simplified the line you have given me to `{{options.aaData = [["A","B","C"],["1","2","3"]];""}}`

Answer (score 0):

So...Setting aaData using `{{options.aaData=JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(@Model.Tests)');""}}` was working but I had nothing monitoring the change meaning the table wasn't being redrawn with the new information.

to track changes I added a watch in my directive, this monitors aaData for changes then updates the table as necessary.

```
scope.$watch('options.aaData', handleUpdate, true);
function handleUpdate(newData) {
                var data = newData || null;
                if (data) {
                    dataTable.fnClearTable();
                    dataTable.fnAddData(newData);
                }
            }
```

my real solution looks a little different now as I am using dataTables ajax call to pull down my json data then setting the dataSrc with the result. Using the in-built ajax calls means I can remove the directive watch as datatables handles this for me.

One final note, if you've found yourself here while figuring out how to mix angularJS & dataTables then this fiddle has helped me a lot.
http://jsfiddle.net/TNy3w/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with angular, take advantage of angular configuration:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        angular.module('app').value('mydata', {
            propOne: '@Url.Action("Index", "Dirty", null)',
            propTwo: angular.fromJson('@Html.Raw(Model.Addresses)')
            // more properties here
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Then you can inject and use 'mydata' anywhere within your angular application

EDIT:
You can create an extension method that serializes your model to JSON, then `Html.Raw` won't give you an error, as long as the parameter you provide is not null.

`public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static string SerializeObject(this object obj) {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                obj,
                new JsonSerializerSettings {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                });
        }
    }`

Then do:

`@using [static extension class namespace here];
...
angular.fromJson('@Html.Raw(Model.Addresses.SerializeObject())')`

Comment: @Html.Raw is causing an error for me, but this is an ideal answer