# Fill JS Array from List<string> C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `List<string>` in my Model C# filled on runtime, called `@Model.Names` in my Views.

After filling that list I want to fill an array in javascript from values of that list, in order to do the following:

```
 var myArray = [];

//fill myArray with values from @Model.Names

 $("#tags").autocomplete({
   source: myArray 
  });
```

So when the user types in `<input id="tags">` he will get an autocomplete with a list of the names I filled on runtime.

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470702/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-liststring-to-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer this way. No manual Looping, and you can do this with fairly complex viewmodels as well (as long as there are no recursive references within your types).

```
var myArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Names))

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: myArray 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = [];
    @foreach (var name in Model.Names)
    {
        @:myArray.push("@name");
    }
</script>
```