# Convert asp.net mvc c# list within a list to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays

I have these Models.

```
public class ModelA
{
  List<ModelB> ModelB {get;set;}
}

public class ModelB
{
  List<ModelC> ModelC {get;set}
}
```

Now, I tried to convert in my script the models above base from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651254/4646236) in my view.

```
<script>
        var modelB = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ModelB))';
        var modelBData = JSON.parse(modelB);

        // Here comes the problem...
        var modelC = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ModelB.ModelC))';

</script>
```

I can convert the Model B to javascript array but failed to convert ModelC into a javascript array. Now, how can I convert the list of ModelC in ModelB into a javascript array?  I was hoping someone might be able to spot where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Let's say `ModelA` contained three `ModelB` items. The first `ModelB` contains one `ModelC`. The second `ModelB` contains two `ModelC`. The third contains three. How many `ModelC` items are you expecting to see in your `Here comes the problem` JSON?

Comment: I need it all actually. I think you're not getting my point

Comment: Can you update your post with the generated HTML (View Source in your browser) for the `modelB` and `modelBData` lines? (after commenting out `var modelC` and other lines that don't compile)

Comment: Could you include the generated HTML @progammer101 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var modelC = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ModelB.ModelC))';
```

should be changed to:

```
var modelC = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ModelB.SelectMany(z => z.ModelC)))';
```

The `SelectMany` will mean you serialise **all** `ModelC` objects that occur in any of the `ModelB` objects.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the scenario is. I need to serialize All ModelC objects per ModelB objects

Comment: It didn't work, sorry for the late reply. i tried using alert on each item on ModelC and shows 'undefined'

Comment: `var ModelC = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ModelB.SelectMany(m => m.ModelC)))';``var modelC = JSON.parse(modelC);`
        `$.each(modelC, function () {
            alert(ModelC.Description);
        });`

Comment: jquery's `each` doesn't work like that (to be explicit - you are using `ModelC` variable without declaring it). Look at the `// Outputs: one two three` example at https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-function-examples/ .