# how to acces list object inside javascript funtion asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#

this is my list in c# view

```
@model SmartFeedBackModel.Models.Question;
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@{
List<SmartFeedBackModel.Models.Question> list = ViewBag.Questions;

 }
```

this is my java script function

```
var i = 0;
    var qustid = 0 ;
    function aaa() {
        var a = @list[0].Answer1;
        alert(a);
        qustid = 22;
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

cannot assign value to variable a

Comment: both list and the js function are on the same view.so i need to get the list elements inside the js function and after that will display one by one manually by button click..if you have a better solution,let me know.thanks in advanced

Comment: if you able to show an alert this element "@list[0].Answer1" .its better

Comment: @NightOwl888 Not actually, the list value will be generated and inserted to html (if the script in same view). sandun If you open your browsers console, you should see there error, which will look something like this  `ReferenceError: <Answer1 value> is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `@list[0].Answer1` to `'@list[0].Answer1'`

This will allow you to assign string razor values to a javascript variable.

Comment: var i =0 ;

        function aaa() {
           
            a = '@list[i].QuestionID';
           alert(a);
            i = i + 1;
        }  //here i need increment the i value..but error occurs saying name 'i' does not exist in the current context.plz hlp if you knok

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use C# Objects directly in JavaScript. What you are trying to do is something like this.

```
On Server
--> Get the object & assign it to list.
--> create a script where line is var a = value of @list[0].Answer1

On Client 
--> Try to run  a = value of @list[0].Answer1
```

This doesn't work. Instead, you need to parse the `list` to JSON or JS Array. So, it will be something like this.

```
var jsList = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(list))');
var i = 0;
var qustid = 0;
    function aaa() {
        var a = jsList[i].Answer1;
        alert(a);
        qustid = 22;
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

I'm assuming you need all the answers on client side and after calling `aaa()` you need to display next answer.

This is for converting C# array to JS Array.

[How do I convert a C# List<string[]> to a Javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470702/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-liststring-to-a-javascript-array)

Edit:
`Json.Encode` is not supported in .NET Core. Instead use `Json.Serialize()`updated the above code.

Comment: You can use c# objects in JS, if he add quotes `''` or `""` it will work fine, but anyway, it is not the best way to achieve that.

Comment: @SeM I know, I think what he want is that entire object. Not just one value.

Comment: I recommend this answer, its best to load the data to the client side then do whatever needs to be done on the JavaScript side. To be quiet frank, try reducing razor code to avoid slowness in rendering the page (since it is server side) - which is my biggest issue that I am facing with razor.

Comment: The best solution would be, if he will create a proper View Model, then use its values.

Comment: there is an error in  Json.Encode .what should i do to avoid it

Comment: i'm using .net core .so if there is  another way to do this plz hlp

Comment: "IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? "  this is the error...