# Unable to pass an asp.net mvc session value to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a Session value from MVC controller to my jascript variable.
Here is what i have tried

--ASP.NET MVC Controller--

```
Session["UserGroups"] = model.Groupes as List<string>;
```

--JS----

```
<script>
    var my_groups = '@Session["UserGroups"]'; 
    console.log(my_groups);
</script>
```

--Output--

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

I would appreciate any help or another approach i can use to achieve my goal.
Thanks

Comment: You need to convert your session object to json. Some answers here should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470702/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-liststring-to-a-javascript-array

Comment: It's a List, which doesn't directly translate to a JS object. It's is implicitly calling ToString so that's why you see that. Did you want it as a comma-separate string, an array, or some other type, perhaps JSON serialized?